# :ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE after two minutes timeout -axios-post - nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, axios, timeout

I'm trying do make an upload of a file in a nodejs / react application. 
The upload of the file work well, but I have some issues when I want to have the response of my `await.post()` request. When I upload the file I have made a spinner to show that the file is uploading, and I want this spinner to stop when the upload is finish and then display a message to inform the user that the loading is finish.

I explain the problems, because it's a little bit complicated.

When i work in local :

After two minutes (I timed it to understand), the console of my browser display the error message `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.
But in server side everything continue and the request ended without a hitch. But in front side my spinner never stop turning even when the request is over and when my post request is sending the res message to my client side.

I thought this was about the timeout of my server, so I've done a lot of test, by putting setTimeout in my server :

```
var server = app.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`)
);

server.timeout = 3840000;
```

And also in my route request :

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  req.setTimeout(3600000);
```

And even i try to change the timeout of my `axios.post` function in the client side :

```
const res = await axios.post('/api/students', newFile, {
      timeout: 3600000,
    });
```

But nothing handle my problem.

And what is strange is that when the application is hosted, the problem is different!

In fact there are no error message but after 1 minutes the spinner stop with no reason.

I have made a lot of research but nothing answer my problem, it's been a few day now that i'm on it and i don't understand why. I thought maybe it's a proxy problem or a browser timeout, but I don't know...

If you have even a small lead, it could help me a lot! Thank you for your help !

UPDATE :

The code of my /api/student route

```
      const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const Student = require('../../models/Student');
const CSVToJSON = require('csvtojson');
const utf8 = require('utf8');
var accents = require('remove-accents');

const NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout);

let msg = 'Etudiants ajoutés à la base de données';

//The column that we want to keep in the database
const goodColumn = [
  'Civilite',
  'Nom_patronymique',
  'Prenom',
  'Date_naissance',
  'No_etudiant',
  'Libelle_nationalite',
  'Telephone_portable',
  'Mailum',
  'Adresse_fixe_postal',
  'Adresse_fixe_ville',
  'Libelle_etape',
];

// Set up the environnement for geocoding the adress
const options = {
  provider: 'openstreetmap',
};

const geoCoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

//FUNCTION TO VERIFY IF A STRING HAS A NUMBER IN IT
function hasNumber(myString) {
  return /\d/.test(myString);
}

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  // This should be BEFORE `fileUpload`
  req.setTimeout(0);
  next();
});

router.use(fileUpload());

//@route   POST api/students
//@desc    Fill the database with the json information
//@access  Public
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  //FORMER FILES ROUTES
  //take the information
  const buf = Buffer.from(req.files.file.data).toString();

  //CONVERSION CSV STRING TO JSON
  CSVToJSON()
    .fromString(buf)
    .then((source) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(source[i]).length; j++) {
          const columnName = Object.keys(source[i]);
          columnName.forEach((element) => {
            if (!goodColumn.includes(element)) {
              delete source[i][element];
            }
            if (element == 'Libelle_etape') {
              const str = source[i]['Libelle_etape'];
              const result = accents.remove(utf8.decode(str));
              source[i]['Libelle_etape'] = result;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      data = JSON.stringify(source);
      datajson = JSON.parse(data);
      //USE THE FUNCTION TO PUT THE DATA IN THE DB
      insertIntoDataBase(datajson);
    });

  // CLEAR TABLE BEFORE ADD NEW STUDENTS FROM FILE
  Student.deleteMany({}, function (err) {});

  //ROUTES STUDENTS - FUNCTION  TO PUT THE JSON DATA IN THE DATABASE
  async function insertIntoDataBase(jsonString) {
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonString.length; i++) {
      console.log(`boucle ${i}`);

      try {
        //READ DATA FROM DE CSV FILE (already convert into json data) AND PUT IT INTO VARIABLES
        let {
          Civilite,
          Nom_patronymique,
          Prenom,
          Date_naissance,
          No_etudiant,
          Libelle_nationalite,
          Telephone_portable,
          Mailum,
          Adresse_fixe_postal,
          Adresse_fixe_ville,
          Libelle_etape,
        } = jsonString[i];
        console.log(Nom_patronymique + ' ' + Prenom);

        // VERIFICATION VILLE STRING FORMAT ( AVOIR NUMBER OR ..EME)
        if (hasNumber(Adresse_fixe_ville)) {
          Adresse_fixe_ville = Adresse_fixe_ville.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
          if (Adresse_fixe_ville.endsWith(' EME')) {
            Adresse_fixe_ville = Adresse_fixe_ville.substring(
              0,
              Adresse_fixe_ville.length - 4
            );
          }
        }

        //VERIFICATION OF THE PHONE NUMBER - if empty attributes a default value
        if (Telephone_portable !== undefined && Telephone_portable.length < 1) {
          Telephone_portable = '0000000000';
        }

        // GEOCODING THE ADDRESS TO CONVERT INTO LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE

        geoCoder
          .geocode({
            city: Adresse_fixe_ville,
            zipcode: Adresse_fixe_postal,
          })
          .then(async (res) => {
            //TEST

            var Latitude;
            var Longitude;
            if (res[0] !== undefined) {
              Latitude = res[0].latitude;
              Longitude = res[0].longitude;
            } else {
              console.log(Adresse_fixe_ville);
              Latitude = 0.0;
              Longitude = 0.0;
            }

            //CREATE A STUDENT WITH THE INFO + LAT AND LONG
            student = new Student({
              Civilite,
              Nom_patronymique,
              Prenom,
              Date_naissance,
              No_etudiant,
              Libelle_nationalite,
              Telephone_portable,
              Mailum,
              Adresse_fixe_postal,
              Adresse_fixe_ville,
              Libelle_etape,
              Latitude,
              Longitude,
            });
            //VERIFICATION IF ALL THE ATTRIBUTE OF THE STUDENT ARE OK - IF NOT : undefined
            if (
              !(
                student.Civilite === undefined ||
                student.Nom_patronymique === undefined ||
                student.Prenom === undefined ||
                student.Date_naissance === undefined ||
                student.No_etudiant === undefined ||
                student.Libelle_nationalite === undefined ||
                student.Telephone_portable === undefined ||
                student.Mailum === undefined ||
                student.Adresse_fixe_postal === undefined ||
                student.Adresse_fixe_ville === undefined ||
                student.Libelle_etape === undefined
              )
            ) {
              //SAVE THE STUDENT IN THE DATABASE
              await student.save();
            } else {
              res.status(500);
              msg =
                'Le fichier csv téléchargé est au mauvais format de données';
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500);
        msg =
          'Erreur serveur, veuillez réessayer avec un fichier csv au bon format';
        return;
      }

      //WAIT FOR GEOCODER - 1,2 second
      await sleep(1200);
    }
    //COUNT A MANY STUDENT WE HAVE IN THE DATABASE
    Student.find().exec(function (err, results) {
      var count = results.length;
      res.json({ msg: msg, count: count });
    });
  }
});

//@route   GET api/students
//@desc    Return all the students in the database (all information / attributes)
//@access  Public
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  Student.find(function (err, students) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    }
    res.json(students);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: can you show the route for: `/api/students` please.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I add it to the end of the pose, i put it in entire for more informaiton but a lot of the code are useless for the problem

Comment: how big is the file you're uploading?

Comment: It a huge file, it's a csv with 1300 ligne, it's take approximatly 30min to upload...

Comment: when i upload a light verison of the csv which take less then 2minutes, i don't have the problem, no error in the consol and the spinner stopped

Comment: Check my update.

Answer (score 1):

In Node `< 13.0.0` the default socket timeout is 2 minutes, so after two minutes the socket will be closed and you'll get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on the client-side since the socket was closed without allowing you to respond to that request.

From Node `13.0.0` the default timeout was set to `0` (no timeout), and that's maybe the reason it works when you deployed the application, your server may be running Node `>= 13.0.0`.

If after using `req.setTimeout` with a value greater to 2 minutes, and you still have that issue, it may be caused because you're not ending the request correctly or you have used `req.setTimeout` in the wrong place.

> It a huge file, it's a csv with 1300 ligne, it's take approximatly
>   30min to upload

From your comment, I can tell you that the `req.setTimeout` you have in your route is not doing what you want, because you have a middleware before that, probably `multer` from seeing at your code that is not setting the `req.setTimeout` to `>30 min`.

So the request is timing out before it reaches your route. You should do something like this:

```
app.post(
    '/', 
    (req, res, next) => {
        // Set request setTimeout BEFORE any other middlewares
        req.setTimeout(ms('35m')); // using `ms` package
        next();
    },
    upload.single('file'), // or whatever multer setup you have
    (req, res, next) => {
        // Your route

    }
)
```

With this code, you have 35 minutes to upload & end your response, since it won't timeout at `multer` middleware after 2 minutes. Of course if you don't know how much time it will take, most likely the case, you can use `req.setTimeout(0)` or whatever value you consider appropiate.

---

**Update**

For your code, you'll have to do the following:

```
// or router.use((req, res, next) => ...)
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
   // This should be BEFORE `fileUpload`
   req.setTimeout(0);
   next();
});

router.use(fileUpload());

//@route   POST api/students
//@desc    Fill the database with the json information
//@access  Public
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
   // ...rest of your code
})
```

Comment: I use fileUpload() to upload the file, i will try your answer thank you very much , do you think it's someting like this ?
`
`router.post(
  '/',
  async (req, res, next) => {
    req.setTimeout(ms('35m'));
    next();
  },
  (req, res, next) => {
    //FORMER FILES ROUTES
    //take the information
    const buf = Buffer.from(req.files.file.data).toString();

    //CONVERSION CSV STRING TO JSON
 [.....] `

Because i d'ont have  something like you in your example uplaod.single(file)

Comment: you're missing your file upload middleware, the file upload middleware **must** be after *req.setTimeout` just as my example.

Comment: I'm not sure I have an upload middlware like you said... is this this line : 
`router.use(fileUpload());`

Comment: don't use it there. do what I said in the request:

router.use((req, res, next) => req.setTimeout(0), fileUpload())

Comment: An alternative is: 

router.use((req, res, next) => req.setTimeout(0); next())
router.use(fileUpload());

Comment: I'm sorry to not unterstand ... but as you can see in my code of my route I don't have a fileupload () like you said or a middlware in my route, just get the file by doing `req.files.file.data`.
And i don't undertand in your response why you have two `(req,res,next) {}`
Because if I do my route in the second (req,res,next) function, I don't have my file in the second req, it's only knwon in the first one.

Comment: Node.js & express does not handle `formData`, so you're using a middleware to handle that. You have to setTimeout BEFORE that middleware :). If you post your full code of the route I can tell you.

Comment: Ok thank you, i try your solution (update my code in my post with your solution) , but it's still not workin, i still have the error message empty repsonse after 2 minutes...

Comment: Then you have something else on your express setup that you're not showing. Because using req.setTimeout greater than 2 min, you won't get that. Try using curl

Comment: Ok thks, i will look for curl , i put the github repository, maybe you will see something that i don't ;) 
https://github.com/CamilleThomasIG3/carpoolingApplication

Comment: I try to use curl, and when I made the console log for the requet post is  : curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "/api/students"

I don't know whats bring's more.. maybe i don't understand the avantage of curl ...

But I keep loking for an express setup that i maybe have but really i have no idea, do you have any idea what kind of setup I could unintentionally get?

Comment: If you have something else going on before the fileUpload, that could cause your route setting the timeout to not be processed, since the timeout occurred before that. You can also use a global timeout for all the server, although it's better to use route specific.

`server.setTimeout(0)` on your server setup
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Comment: I already try to set a global timeout by adding `server.timeout = 3840000;` in the server.js file but doesn't work ...

Comment: do you have nginx or something else before your Node.js app?, It's hard to help you if we can't reproduce the error.

Comment: I don't seem to have nginx no .

Comment: For me, the mistake can come from: 
The request axios. But I tried to do add : axios.defaults.timeout = 3600000; in my action/file.js but doesn't suceed.
I've also seen that sometimes it was due to the browser... But can't find a solution
I don't know...

Comment: But concerning nginx i use OpenstreetMap to geoCode my adress into coordinate. And it seem like OpenStreet map are maybe link to nginx, i don't know if it's have an importance or not..